# Rstudio qsslearnr package Tutorial is not installing a pdf on the Submit page

Tags: r, pdf, file-not-found

I followed the instructions to download the qsslearnr packages here:https://github.com/mattblackwell/qsslearnr and was able to complete a tutorial. However, when I get to the Submit page, I click the Download PDF button, but I get a .htm file that I cannot open. I get an error saying that the file may be "deleted or moved". I have looked around online and can't seem to find a solution to the issue - any help is appreciated. Thank you and have a good day!

The error:
Your file couldn’t be accessed
It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

This is what shows up in the console after clicking "Download PDF":

```
processing file: tutorial-report.Rmd
                                                                                                            
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS tutorial-report.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc42e45926820.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
output file: tutorial-report.knit.md

Warning in system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  '"pdflatex"' not found
Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgbUVge\file42e46006610.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
  9: <Anonymous>
  7: rmarkdown::run
  4: run_tutorial
  3: eval
  2: eval
  1: .rs.sourceWithProgress
```

I tried changing my default app for opening pdf files to Adobe Acrobat Reader and tried saving the file to a different folder, which did not solve the issue.

`sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/Los_Angeles
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readr_2.1.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_4.0.5         jsonlite_1.8.8    renv_1.0.3        crayon_1.5.2      compiler_4.3.2   
 [6] promises_1.2.1    tidyselect_1.2.0  Rcpp_1.0.11       parallel_4.3.2    later_1.3.2      
[11] yaml_2.3.8        fastmap_1.1.1     mime_0.12         R6_2.5.1          knitr_1.45       
[16] backports_1.4.1   htmlwidgets_1.6.4 checkmate_2.3.1   tibble_3.2.1      rprojroot_2.0.4  
[21] shiny_1.8.0       pillar_1.9.0      tzdb_0.4.0        rlang_1.1.2       utf8_1.2.4       
[26] httpuv_1.6.13     xfun_0.41         bit64_4.0.5       cli_3.6.2         withr_2.5.2      
[31] magrittr_2.0.3    learnr_0.11.5     digest_0.6.33     vroom_1.6.5       rstudioapi_0.15.0
[36] xtable_1.8-4      remotes_2.4.2.1   hms_1.1.3         lifecycle_1.0.4   vctrs_0.6.5      
[41] evaluate_0.23     glue_1.6.2        fansi_1.0.6       rmarkdown_2.25    tools_4.3.2      
[46] pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.2    htmltools_0.5.7
```

Comment: I've had a look at the [source code](https://github.com/mattblackwell/qsslearnr/blob/main/R/submission.R) but nothing stands out. Are you able to please edit your question to include the output of the command `sessionInfo()` @fluffs77?

Comment: @jared_mamrot I have added the output to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Good idea trying a different folder. It looks like a latex issue; try `install.packages("tinytex"); tinytex::install_tinytex()` and see if you get any error messages. If there are no errors, try the 'Download PDF' button again.

Comment: @jared_mamrot I tried the tinytex and the PDF button works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem @fluffs77 